# Setting my timezone and language to datetime from timestamp database value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have a Template table (id,name,created_at,upated_at)and Im looping it showing this its name and updated datetime

- template 1 | february, 2, 2018
- template 2 | january, 3, 2018
- template 3 | january, 7, 2018

That's ok, the problem is that I am from Brazil and I need it to show it in my format and language

- template 1 | 2, FEVEREIRO,  2018
- template 2 | 3, JANEIRO, 2018
- template 3 | 7, JANEIRO, 2018

I am trying to use Mutator on eloquent Laravel but it not working at all, I just COPIED the WHOLE script from the documentation and still resfues to work.

And happens that EVEN UPPERCASE functions are not working as well, just like nothing would happen in this "mutators system".

Model:

```
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute()
{
    $this->attributes['updated_at']->format('d/m/Y H:I');
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($templates as $template)
              <h2>Nome: {{$template->name}}</h2>
                  <h6>Data: 
                      @foreach($template as $temp)
                      {{$temp->updated_at}}  
                      @endforeach
                  </h6>
@endforeach
```

So any help would be great, thank you

Comment: have you tried, accessor `getUpdatedAtAttribute()` instead? Since you are trying to retrieve and you are not trying to save that attribute.

Comment: thank you, but nothing happens, it is like this function barely exists

Answer (score 0):

use strftime of PHP, it will work fine. No need of plugins

reference link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

sample code:

```
  setlocale(LC_TIME, "pt_BR");
  echo strftime(" in Finnish is %A,");
```

I hope this helps !!